# Periodically call a C function without manually creating a thread

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, timer

I have implemented a WebSocket handler in C++ and I need to send ping messages once in a while. However, I don't want to start one thread per socket/one global poll thread which only calls the ping function but instead use some OS functionality to call my timer function. On Windows, there is `SetTimer` but that requires a working message loop (which I don't have.) On Linux there is `timer_create`, which looks better.

Is there some portable, low-overhead method to get a function called periodically, ideally with some custom context? I.e. something like `settimer (const int millisecond, const void* context, void (*callback)(const void*))`?

[**Edit**] Just to make this a bit clearer: I don't want to have to manage additional threads. On Windows, I guess using `CreateThreadpoolTimer` on the system thread pool will do the trick, but I'm curious to hear if there is a simpler solution and how to port this over to Linux.

Comment: Will the release be for Linux, Windows, or both?

Comment: If you don't have an event loop, scheduling a "timer" with a callback is not possible

Comment: If you don't have a working message loop, Windows will notice that your app isn't pumping the message loop and will mark it as "hung" and possibly terminate it.

Comment: I need something for both Windows and Linux, but I'm fine with separate code paths.

Comment: That's why I'm asking how to do it a) without an additional thread and b) without a message pump.

Comment: @RichardTurner: that's valid for GUI applications on Windows.  Any process without a (visible) window is not subject to being randomly killed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to go cross-platform, I would suggest you use a cross platform event library like [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

[libev](http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html) is newer, however currently has weak Win32 support.

Comment: Both libraries are based on `select()` for Windows, which is [inherently limited, as documented by `libev`](http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html#win32_platform_limitations_and_workarounds).  I doubt any library based on this design are ever going to have anything better than "weak" support for Windows.

Comment: But if @Anteru is looking for a simple timer callback, it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sockets, you can use select, to wait sockets events with timeout,
and in this loop calc time and call callback in suitable time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a timer that will not require an additional thread, let you do your work transparently and then call the timer function at the appropriate time in the same thread by pre-emptively interrupting your application, then there is no such portable thing.

The first reason is that it's downright dangerous.  That's like writing a multi-threaded application with *absolutely no synchronization*.  The second reason is that it is extremely difficult to have good semantics in multi-threaded applications.  Which thread should execute the timer callback?

If you're writing a web-socket handler, you are probably already writing a `select()`-based loop.  If so, then you can just use `select()` with a short timeout and check the different connections for which you need to ping each peer.

Comment: It's fine if it is running on another thread; I just don't want to create that thread on my own and I want to share the threads among all my sockets. Right now I'm inclined to use the Windows Thread Pool to schedule timer callbacks, but what is the POSIX equivalent for this?

Comment: Have you checked [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)?

Comment: Yeah, and nothing in Boost.Asio looks lightweight.

Comment: That's partially because it actually provides a good abstraction of the native networked programming models on different platforms.  And because it uses other boost libraries for smart pointers, function callbacks, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have asynchronous events, you should have an event loop.  This doesn't need to be some system default one, like Windows' message loop.  You can create your own.  But you should be using it.

The whole point about event-based programming is that you are decoupling your code handling to deal with well-defined functional fragments based on these asynchronous events.  Without an event loop, you are condemning yourself to interleaving code that get's input and produces output based on poorly defined "states" that are just fragments of procedural code.

Without a well-defined separation of states using an event-based design, code quickly becomes unmanageable.  Because code pauses inside procedures to do input tasks, you have lifetimes of objects that will not span entire procedure scopes, and you will begin to write if (nullptr == xx) in various places that access objects created or destroyed based on events.  Dispatch becomes comnbinatorially complex because you have different events expected at each input point and no abstraction.

However, simply using an event loop and dispatch to state machines, you've decreased handling complexity to basic management of handlers (O(n) handlers versus O(mn) branch statements with n types of events and m states).  You decouple handling but still allow for functionality to change depending on state.  But now these states are well-defined using state classes.  And new states can be added if the requirements of the product change.

I'm just saying, stop trying to avoid an event loop.  It's a software pattern for very important reasons, all of which have to do with producing professional, reusable, scalable code.  Use Boost.ASIO or some other framework for cross platform capabilities.  Don't get in the habit of doing it wrong just because you think it will be less of an effort.  In the end, even if it's not a professional project that needs maintenance long term, you want to practice making your code professional so you can do something with your skills down the line.